# ArcGIS Pro - Spatial Join between layers. High granularity polygons as target

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join

Even though I found an easier way to achieve the result (using numerical data provided with the dataset), I would still like to see if what I tried to do using Spatial Join is correct, or even possible.

I extracted few provinces from a Spanish file that had polygons of all provinces. This layer with 3 provinces is my area of interest.

Underneath I have a layer with postcodes. Unfortunately the province layer is not as detailed as the postcodes, hence it doesn't align perfectly.

I tried to use Spatial Join in order to attach name of the province only to the postcodes that are  within the province.

But "within" in this sense is not aligned and I'm having a trouble getting the result.

I tried different types of joins Within, Have their center in, and so on.

Pink layer is my province - join features.
Green layer are postcodes - target features.

[image]

The closest I got was using "Have Their Center In" but there's one postcode area in a shape that the centroid is actually outside of the province polygon:

[image]

Is my way even  a correct way to do it or should I use a different tool?

Comment: Using the LARGEST_OVERLAP match option might give you what you want.

Comment: I tried it. The problem is that other province polygons do not exist anymore hence those ones that are in the layer will still be the largest overlaping.

Comment: Compare area of intersect and actual. If above certain threshold...

Comment: @FelixIP I tried that but shouldn't the resulting ShapeArea be exactly the same (100%) of those that are totally included in the larger shape?

Comment: Got it working by doing Intersect, joining back to original feature class and then using selection on % coverage.. Thanks!